# Bootstrap h-100 and vertically centering content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I have a `div` that is a Bootstrap `col` and is set to `h-100`. The content in this `div` is currently aligned to the top. If the content is larger than the viewport height, then the content scrolls.

If the content in this `div` is smaller than the viewport height, I want it centered vertically.

Not sure if this is any help, but here is the HTML for the `div` in question:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-12 h-md-100 p-3 overflow-md-auto">
```

The `h-md-100` is a custom class that only applies the `h-100` styles if the viewport width is `md` (768px) or larger.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `align-self-center`? That will vertically center the content in the center of the column

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-12 d-flex flex-column align-self-center ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Content 2</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```